# Do hooks exist for every modification to a git repository?

Tags: git, notifications, githooks

As a learning project, I want to make a git visualizer that shows the underlying git commit graph in real time. To do this, my visualization program needs to receive updates every time the graph changes.

I know that git has hooks for a number of commands. My question is: do the post-XXXXX hooks cover the entire space of ways that the git repository can be changed?

A follow up question: is there a better way for a process to "listen" to a git repo programmatically? The downside of using the git hooks is that I would have to modify the repo in order to visualize it. Ideally, I wouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While git command line utility processes hooks, there are other ways to change git object store. Some of these methods do not necessarily process hooks.

For example, very popular git library [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) currently [does not honor hooks](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/964). Quite a few utilities make use of libgit2.

Also, one can use `git commit -n` to turn off hooks even in command line.

In other words, hooks do NOT guarantee that you will see every single update to the git object store.

Alternative way for you to pay attention of what is changing is probably simply watching branch pointers. This should be very cheap process. You can also setup OS native methods on listening on changes to branch files (like [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) for Linux and [FindFirstChangeNotification/WaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Windows).